# Retroactively change Permalinks for media files after disabling year/month format

Tags: uploads, media-library

Disabling "Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folders" works as expected for new files uploaded. What I have not been able to find is if there is a way to also "move/redirect" past files that are in the /uploads/xxxx/xx folder structure into the new /uploads/ folder.

I ran a dB Search and replace for one month /uploads/2022/06 to /uploads/ but that did not work as expected (did not change urls.)

Any thoughts on what I could try next?